# linq query to filter textvalue pair and remove duplicates by value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to filter the results I'm getting by removing some of the items I have in my custom dictionary by their value. So if there are multiple items with the same value I would like to have only one sample of that pair.

This is the custom class I have where I'm storing the values:

```
                public class ValuePair
                {
                    public string Text { get; set; }
                    public string Value { get; set; }
                }
```

Here is how I'm retrieving the values:

```
   List<ValuePair> items = GetResults(db)             
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Distinct()
               .Select(v => new TextValuePair
               {
                   Text = ToTitleCase(v.NameOfTown),
                   Value = v.NameOfTown
               })              
               .ToList();
```

I would like to know how I can refresh the results and get only one sample of the items filtered by the value, not by the key.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `Value` then take the first item of the grouped items.

```
List<ValuePair> items = GetResults(db)             
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Distinct()
           .Select(v => new TextValuePair
           {
               Text = ToTitleCase(v.NameOfTown),
               Value = v.NameOfTown
           })
           .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
           .Where(x => x.Key == "filter") // filter by Value (the prop name is Key)
           .Select(x => x.First()) 
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @tsuta your solution helped me, I'll mark it as an answer in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this  https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/ `librarry` it has an extension method called

`DistictBy`  and then you can

```
 List<ValuePair> items = GetResults(db)             
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Select(v => new TextValuePair
               {
                   Text = ToTitleCase(v.NameOfTown),
                   Value = v.NameOfTown
               }).DisrinctBy(c=>c.Value)           
               .ToList();
```